# Automatically copy correct CLI command to clipboard after failure

Tags: bash, git

Suppose I run:

```
git push
```

And I get the error message:

```
fatal: The current branch cdt-rd has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin cdt-rd
```

Is there a way to conjigger my git or bash so that it automatically copies the correct command (`git push --set-upstream origin cdt-rd`) to my clipboard?

Comment: `echo foo | xclip`?

Answer (score 2):

Would probably be easier to create a smart alias, I use this one:

`git config --global alias.pto '!bash -c "git push --set-upstream ${1-origin} $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)" -'`

Pushes to the origin by default `git pto` or to another remote `git pto remote`

It automatically resolves the current branch name, then pushes the branch to the remote and sets the upstream. Also works if you use this command instead of push if the upstream is already set.

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global push.default current
```

You should only have to do this once. Then,

```
git push
```